# How to open a file from CLI using a text editor of my choice, if the name of application has multiple strings?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, hyperterminal

Im learning to use hyper terminal for my web development. I need to open a file directly from CLI using VSCode.
For opening it using notepad++ i can open it by writing

```
start Notepad++ filename.ext
```

But i want to open it with Visual studio code.For which i wrote

```
start Visual studio Code filename.ext
```

The name of vscode is shown as Visual studio Code in apps. Since it has multiple strings im getting error. how do i bind the name of application together.
Incase if i want to open through atom i write,it works fine.

```
start Atom filename.ext
```

How do i make it work.

Comment: Probably use single quotes: `start 'Visual studio Code' filename.ext`.

Comment: I tried, but it dint work...

start code fname.ext 

worked...Thanks for ur response...

Comment: The name of the program, as shown in Windows Explorer, is irrelevant. When you launch a program, ultimately you need to know its main binary, which in Visual Studio Code is `code.exe`. Your other examples, the commercial name happens to be the same as the exe name. You can look up this by looking at your shortcuts for the command to run. A similar thing would happen with Microsoft Word for example, whose binary is really `winword.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to open Visual studio code through the terminal you need to call it as 'code', so in your case it would be "start code filename.ext".
Be advised I am working in linux, it may be slightly different in windows. You can also look at the properties of vscode and it should say there how to open it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but maybe it will help others.
The command is: code filename.txt

Answer (score -1):

To open Visual Studio code from your Hyper Terminal, just type: **code .**

Comment: How is your answer different from the other answers in to this question?